# looking for faster way to deal with cell and vector operations

Tags: performance, matlab, cell-array

I have a cell list with each elements contains varied number of coordinates to access a vector. For example,

```
C ={ [1 2 3] , [4 5],  [6], [1 8 9 12 20]}
```

this is just an example, in real case, C is of 10^4 to 10^6 size, each element contains a vector of 1 to 1000 elements. I need to use each element as coordinates to access the corresponding elements in a vector. I am using a loop to find the mean value of vector elements specified by the cell elements

```
 for n=1:size(C,1)
   x = mean(X(C{n}));
   % put x to somewhere  
 end
```

here X is the big vector of 10000 elements. Using the loop is ok but I am wondering if any way to do the same thing but without using a loop? The reason I am asking is above code need to be run for so many times and it is quite slow now to use a lopp.

Comment: By coordinates do you mean indices? And shouldn't that be `x(n)` for each cell of C? And also maybe the loop could be - `for n=1:size(C,2)`? `n=1:numel(C)` might suit there better?

Comment: Also let me ask you - How big could be the biggest cell in C? For example in the sample given here, it is `5`, which is in the last cell.

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you profile your code and check what the actual bottleneck is.

Comment: Glad to get the acceptance checkmark, but I would really love to get some feedback/comments on what kinda speedups you are getting at your end with the approaches proposed in the solution, if any. Also, please clarify on the `x(n)` or `x` issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Approach #1**

```
C_num = char(C{:})-0; %// 2D numeric array from C with cells of lesser elements 
             %// being filled with 32, which is the ascii equivalent of space

mask = C_num==32; %// get mask for the spaces
C_num(mask)=1; %// replace the numbers in those spaces with ones, so that we 
                %// can index into x witout throwing any out-of-extent error

X_array = X(C_num); %// 2D array obtained after indexing into X with C_num
X_array(mask) = nan; %// set the earlier invalid space indices with nans
x = nanmean(X_array,2); %// final output of mean values neglecting the nans
```

---

**Approach #2**

```
lens = cellfun('length',C); %// Lengths of each cell in C
maxlens = max(lens); %// max of those lengths

%// Create a mask array with no. of rows as maxlens and columns as no. of cells. 
%// In each column, we would put numbers from each cell starting from top until
%// the number of elements in that cell. The ones(true) in this mask would be the 
%// ones where those numbers are to be put and zeros(false) otherwise.
mask = bsxfun(@le,[1:maxlens]',lens) ; %//'

C_num = ones(maxlens,numel(lens)); %// An array where the numbers from C are to be put

C_num(mask) = [C{:}]; %// Put those numbers from C in C_num.
  %// NOTE: For performance you can also try out: double(sprintf('%s',C{:}))
X_array = X(C_num); %// Get the corresponding X elements
X_array(mask==0) = nan; %// Set the invalid locations to be NaNs
x = nanmean(X_array); %// Get the desired output of mean values for each cell
```

---

**Approach #3**

This would be almost same as approach #2, but with some changes at the end to avoid `nanmean`.

Thus, edit the last two lines from approach #2, to these -

```
X_array(mask1==0) = 0;
x = sum(X_array)./lens;
```

Comment: Note that in Approach #3, it is `mask` and not `mask1`.